Custom Classifier Failed to refresh dataset stats
I'm training a Custom Classifier in Document AI. Worked fine and I had a Dataset with about 4000 documents. I trained multiple versions and they are running well.
But now I'm not able to see these documents in the Dataset anymore and lable them. Im getting the message 'Failed to refresh dataset stats' over and over again.
0 shown but documents are uploaded
When I upload new files they appear as long as the upload is ongoing but when the upload is finished all documents fail to load.
